# Insert a frame to an animation（using UIImageView）

Tags: ios, tomcat, animation, uiimageview, frame

I have made my animation like this （it's a group of images）

```
mainViewGIF.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test2.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test3.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"test4.jpg"],nil];
mainViewGIF.animationDuration = 2.0;
mainViewGIF.animationRepeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
[mainViewGIF startAnimating];
[mainViewGIF release];
```

What I want is to insert a frame (by touching a button)to the animation and this frame play only once, just like "talking Tom"（the cat） when you touch him, he make some kind of action.

Or there is some other kinds of solution? thank u all

Comment: or how to display an image for a short time on the view?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a NSMutableArray and when you press that specific button just:

```
[array addObject:[UIImage imageYouWant]];
```

Then after you finsish the animation try something like:

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:5];
```

Not exactly sure about the syntax of the code, but I hope this pseudo code can help you out!

Best of luck